# overwrite set system properties at runtime in maven pom

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, pom.xml, uigraphicsimagerenderer

I am using org.eclipse.images.renderer plugin to render my images from svg to png. Eclipse has provided support to create highDpi icons as well which requires 2 more arguments to be passed
eclipse.svg.scale=2 and eclipse.svg.createFragments=false (to not create separate folder).
I want to render both normal icons and high-dpi icons both through my pom, but giving those 2 arguments overwrite my configurations and hence for both the executions I get the same type of icons. Is there any way to overwrite the eclipse.svg.scale property to use 1 for one execution and 2 for the second execution. Attaching my POM for reference:

In my POM I have added 2 execution items to render icons and used properties-maven-plugin plugin to set the set-system-properties for setting the properties. But these properties are being set to both the executions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.provar.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.provar.tycho.root</artifactId>
    <version>1.230.0</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.provar.images</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.provar.images</artifactId>
  <version>2.260.0.0</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

  <name>Provar Image Library</name>
  <description>Provar image library and conversion tools</description>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.images</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.images.renderer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.100-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>render-icons</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>highDpi</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>render-icons</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- any phase before your app deploys -->
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <properties>
                <property>
                  <name>eclipse.svg.sourcedirectory</name>
                  <value>${project.basedir}/svg</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                  <name>eclipse.svg.targetdirectory</name>
                  <value>${images.output.folder}/images</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>eclipse.svg.scale</name>
                    <value>2</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>eclipse.svg.createFragments</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </property>
              </properties>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I want to use the eclipse.svg.scale property as 1 for one execution and as 2 for second execution. Is it possible to be done by configuring the POM itself. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a maven "profile" to control specific executions.

[Maven Profiles Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Set up your project with 2 profiles, let's say svgscale1 and svgscale2

Then you invoke the maven build like this:

```
mvn clean install -Psvgscale1
mvn clean install -Psvgscale2
```

Comment: this project is added as a feature in eclipse and the parent pom contains many modules. These modules gets executed one after the other. Is there any way to execute this module twice with different profiles as well?